# Using list comprehension in lieu of two for loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to implement this at one go:

```
W_jk = 0 if |j-k| > X
```

I tried this but it seems error-prone.

```
W[i,j] = [0 if abs(i-j) > X for i in range(0,len(W)) for j in range(0,len(W[0]))]
```

Is there an alternative? Thanks.

[EDIT 1]: `W = np.random.randn(m,d)` for some m, d

[EDIT 2]:

For a subproblem, where W_j1k1 = W_j2k2 when j1-k1 = j2-k2 and |j1-k1|<=X. Can this be done by a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want to assign `0` to selective items within an existing list of lists `W`. If that's the case, it's more efficient to selectively update the items with a nested `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(W)):
    for j in range(len(W[i])):
        if abs(i - j) > X:
            W[i][j] = 0
```

If you don't care about efficiency and just want to make it one line of code, however, you can use the following list comprehension so that it reuses the current value when the condition `|j-k| > X` is not met:

```
W = [[0 if abs(i - j) > X else W[i][j] for j in range(len(W[i]))] for i in range(len(W))]
```

Note that the `W[i,j]` in your question is not the correct syntax to access an item in a list of lists. You should use `W[i][j]` instead.

EDIT: For your sub-problem you can use the following list comprehension, although it is not optimized by any means:

```
W = [[next((W[j2][k2] for j2 in range(len(W)) for k2 in range(len(W[j2])) if j1 - k1 == j2 - k2 and abs(j1 - k1) <= X), W[j1][k1]) for k1 in range(len(W[j1]))] for j1 in range(len(W))]
```

Comment: Noted. But this solution too converts the matrix to a list. How do I retain the original matrix format? I edited the question to show W

Comment: Yes, you can re-instantiate the resulting list of lists as a NumPy array afterwards, although again it would be more efficient to update selective values in-place as the first example code does.

Comment: Okay. Also for the subproblem as edited above, can we do this at one go?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to your sub-problem.

Comment: There's a slight glitch though. Imagine W is 10x20. When I apply W = np.array(W) # Converting the list back to a matrix. , the resultant matrix is 10x4000 when it should be 10x20.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer to use a generator expression instead.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** If your original `W` data structure is a NumPy array, you can do some fancy indexing to avoid looping entirely.

```
import numpy as np
i = np.arange(W.shape[0])
j = np.arange(W.shape[1])
ii, jj = np.meshgrid(j, i)  # note the flipped indices!
absval = np.abs(ii - jj)
mask = absval > X
W[mask] = 0
```

This is considerably faster and more efficient than nested loops.

**ORIGINAL POST**

Several preliminaries:

First, I noticed there wasn't a condition for `abs(i - j) <= X`, so I included an `else 1` condition.

Second, I couldn't tell if `W` already existed (i.e., was pre-allocated), or if you were creating it in the comprehension. I treated it as though it did *not* exist.

Third, the use of `len` in the comprehensions itself is problematic if the answer to the previous question is that `W` does not yet exist.

```
n_rows = 10 # change to suit your needs
n_cols = 5  # change to suit your needs
W = [ [0 if abs(i - j) > X else 1 for i in range(n_cols) ] for j in range(n_rows) ]
```

Comment: To answer your doubts, the else condition will be else W1[i,j]

W already exists. I'm not creating it in the comprehension

One issue is that your solution converts the matrix to a list.